# Question: Webscraping Vector error from sport website

Tags: r, rvest

I'm learning how to analyze using web scraping. However, at the moment I get an error when I use the website that is in the code and grab the season of 2020.

But if I grab the season of 2019 there is nothing wrong.

The error I get is :
Error in names(x) <- value :
names' attribute [27] must be the same length as the vector [20].

What does it mean, and how can I fix this code so I can create a data frame

**Load the data**

```
# Import/ingest the Formula 1 race results for season 2016 ----------------
# Take a look at the data in the browser
browseURL('https://www.formel1.de/rennergebnisse/wm-stand/2020/fahrerwertung')
# Fetch the contents of the HTML-table into the variable f1
f1 <- read_html('https://www.formel1.de/rennergebnisse/wm-stand/2020/fahrerwertung') %>% 
  html_node('table') %>% 
  html_table()
# Display our data
f1
```

This works fine

**Transform the data**

```
# Transform & tidy the data -----------------------------------------------
# Add missing column headers
colnames(f1) <- c('Pos', 'Driver', 'Total', sprintf('R%02d', 1:24))
# Convert to tibble data frame and filter on top 9 drivers
f1 <- as_tibble(f1) %>% 
  filter(as.integer(Pos) <= 10)
# Make Driver a factorial variable, replace all '-' with zeros, convert to long format
f1$Driver <- as.factor(f1$Driver)
f1[, -2] <- apply(f1[, -2], 2, function(x) as.integer(gsub('-', '0', as.character(x))))
f1long <- gather(f1, Race, Points, R01:R21)
# That looks better
f1long
```

**error**
Error in names(x) <- value :
'names' attribute [27] must be the same length as the vector [20]

**Source**
https://www.formel1.de/rennergebnisse/wm-stand/2020/fahrerwertung 2020

https://www.formel1.de/rennergebnisse/wm-stand/2019/fahrerwertung 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the web-scraping, but with the `colnames()`-part.

The table `f1` which you scrape contains 20 columns:

```
ncol(f1)
# [1] 20
```

But your `colnames` has 27 names, premising that `f1` has 27 columns.

You thus need to do two changes to your code:

- Change to `colnames(f1) <- c('Pos', 'Driver', 'Total', sprintf('R%02d', 1:17))` [note the **17** instead of **24**] and it should be fine.
- In addition, change the `gather()`-part to `f1long <- gather(f1, Race, Points, R01:R17)` [again, note the **17** instead of **20**].

(*By the way, instead of `gather()`, it is recommended to use `pivot_longer()` in the future; cf. `?gather` or [see here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html).*)